# Must a flambé be ignited by a Jew to remain kosher?

Tags: halacha, food, fire-burning, bishul-akum

Because of the halacha of Bishul Akum (or Bishul Yisrael, call it what you will), even if a food's ingredients are all kosher, it needs to have a Jew involved in the cooking process for it to be kosher.  There are many details here, and some forms of cooking are different than others.  But what about a [flambé](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flambe): if a non-Jew ignites it, does that make the food non-kosher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the food is already cooked (to the level of Maachal ben Drusai), and the flambé is just adding some flavor, it would not be problematic (Y.D. 113:8)

Comment: The same halacha would apply if the goy was theoretically trying to cook it the rest of the way, but that's not a practical case.